# New Unity Input System to Touch Controls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created an input system for my 2d platformer game. It's a state-machine which I created by following Bardent on Youtube. Now I am trying to create touch controls for the same.

The controls are working but I am not able to do multiple touches on the screen such as pressing the rightmovement button and the jump button simultaneously.

What could be the problem here?

[Action Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh3h9.png)

I tried implementing touch controls by adding button in the Canvas and then using the "On-Screen Button" Component to assign control paths.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is that you have the input set to the Primary Touch/Tap.
This only registers the first tap you make. Try switching the binding to Press (Single Touch), and if that doesn't work, then you might want to manually add the Primary touch tap, and then add the tap for Touch #0, Touch #1, Touch #2, etc.